# Rest Service, Await events before Pipeline disposes resources

Tags: c#, rest, events, async-await, .net-core

I have a generic rest service which executes async events.  Currently I'm using this to send updates from signalr hubs.  My generic service implementation looks like so:

```
public event EventHandler<TDTO> OnCreate;
protected virtual void OnCreated(TDTO dto) { OnCreate?.Invoke(this, dto); }

public async Task<TDTO> Create(TDTO dto)
{
    var entity = this.DtoToEntity(dto, new TEntity());
    this._context.Set<TEntity>().Add(entity);

    dto = await this.SaveEntity(entity);
    this.OnCreated(dto);
    return dto;
}
```

I'm using asynchronous delegates I'm subscribing to the on create event:

```
rs.OnCreate += async (object obj, MessageDTO dto) =>
{
    var context = sp.GetService<AstootContext>();
    var isFirstMessage = await context.Conversations.Where(x => x.Id == dto.ConversationId).Where(x => x.Messages.Count == 1).AnyAsync();

    if(isFirstMessage)
    {
        var hubContext = sp.GetService<IHubContext<CRUDServiceHubBase<Conversation>>>();
        var conversationService = sp.GetService<IRestEzService<Conversation, ConversationDTO>>();
        var conversationDTO = await conversationService.Get(new object[] { dto.ConversationId });
        await hubContext.Clients.All.SendAsync(CRUDServiceHubBase.CreateEventName, conversationDTO)
                        .ConfigureAwait(false);      
    }
};
```

However I'm getting an error, in when I `await conversationService.Get`,   The Http Pipeline shuts down before my events are complete.

I do not want to change to use the observer pattern because this is will causing breaking changes.

I want to continue using async to free my thread, for network operations etc.

How can I have the make sure the Pipeline waits for my events to complete before disposing of my resources?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you're not awaiting `OnCreated` the `Create` might return before `OnCreated` completes its execution.

You might want to revise your design because this will require to go throw the invocation list of `OnCreated` and await the result of the execution of all delegates.